# Qt nested QGraphicsItem coordinates

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I would expect, from documentation, that this snippet

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QGraphicsView *v = new QGraphicsView(new QGraphicsScene);
    setCentralWidget(v);

    QGraphicsRectItem *r1 = v->scene()->addRect(QRectF(100,100, 200,200), QPen(), QBrush(Qt::red));
    QGraphicsRectItem *r2 = new QGraphicsRectItem(r1);
    r2->setRect(QRectF(10,10, 50,50));
    r2->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::blue));
}
```

would draw a blue rect *inside* the red one, instead here is the result:

[image]

Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I miss something?

Yes.

Calling `setRect()` on a `QGraphicsRectItem` does not actually change its `pos()`, it just changes the position of the rectangle that it draws, but the item's position is unchanged. Thus, your `r1` has a pos of (0, 0), but its rectangle is drawn at a (100, 100) offset to its `pos()`.

To avoid confusion, it's usually easier to leave your rect at (0, 0) and call `setPos()` on your `QGraphicsRectItem` to move it where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the blue rectangle inside the red one, you could either set its rect position in screen coordinates, or set the blue rectangle as the parent of the red rectangle with setParentItem. That way, the child's position is set relative to its parent.